# Python sockets; sending from client receiving on server

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send messages on TCP/IP all on host machine. This is working, although for some reason the socket needs to be re-instantiated for every new message on the client side only. For example here is a basic client that sends three separate messages:

```
import socket


host = '127.0.0.1'

class Client:
    def __init__(self):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

    def connect(self):
        self.sock.connect((host,12347))

    def send(self,message):
            self.sock.sendall(message)
    def close(self):
        self.sock.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    message1 = "I am message 1"
    message2 = "I am message 2"
    message3 = "I am message 3"

    #exp = Client()
    #exp.connect()

    for i in range(0,3):
        try:
            exp = Client()
            exp.connect()
            if i == 0:
                txt = message1
            elif i == 1:
                txt = message2
            elif i == 2:
                txt = message3
                exp.send(txt)
                exp.close()

            print i
            exp.send(txt)

        except:
            pass
```

and the server that receives:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket


class communication:


  def __init__(self):
    try:

      host = '127.0.0.1'

      self.Server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

      self.Server.bind((host,12347))

      self.Server.listen(1)

    finally:

      print "setup finished"



  def recieve(self):

    (connection, client_address) = self.Server.accept()

    data = connection.recv(128)

    return data



  def close(self):

    self.server.close()





if __name__ == "__main__":



    exp = communication()



    while True:

        try:

            (connection,client_address) = exp.Server.accept()

            message = connection.recv(128)

        finally:

            print message



        if message == "I am message 3":

          exp.close()
```

You see how I re-call the Client class in each iteration of the for loop. This seems to be necessary for sending messages 2 and 3. If the socket is instantiated only once at the start of the main code along with the connect() function, then the server hangs on the recv() after the first message has been sent.

I can't understand why this is happening and the socket only needs to be setup once on the server side. I am doing something wrong, or is this normal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's even worse than you think. Take a look at your server code. `exp.Server.accept()` accepts a connection from the client, but `connection.receive()` ignores that connection completely and does a second `self.Server.accept()`. You ignore half of your connections!

Next, your server only does a single receive.... Even if you tried to send more messages on the connection, the server would ignore them.

But you can't just add a recv loop. Your client and server need some way to mark message boundaries so the server knows how to pull them out. Some text based systems use a new line. Others send a message size or fixed size header that the server can read. HTTP for example uses a combination of new lines and data count.

If you want to learn sockets from the ground up just know that they are complicated and you'll need to study. There are lots of ways to build a server and you'll need to understand the trade-offs. Otherwise, there are many frameworks from XMLRPC to zeromq that do some of the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. And thanks for spotting the mistake in my code. So The server basically needs to know when one message has ended? I'm slightly confused because it seems to work fine when the client socket is recreated after each message. Surely the server is unaware of what's going on on the client side? I thought it just listens in on the relevant port?